# Angular ui-grid does not display properly on small screen devices(Mobile Phones)

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

Using Angular ui-grid latest version (4.0.0) having 6 columns and it displays correctly on laptop/desktop(Big screens) but displays very badly in small screen devices(Mobile phones), data get cut with (...) and columns display one below the other. Anything to fix it?

Comment: add width property in the coldefs object.

Comment: Thanks, We already using the columnDefs with column width in % but it was not coming, though, I have figured it out actually parent div was given 100% width so it's taking viewport width and adjust grid accordingly but when parent width removed it's works!!!

Answer (score 0):

We already using the columnDefs with column width in % but it was not coming, though, I have figured it out actually parent div was given 100% width so it's taking viewport width and adjust grid accordingly but when parent width removed its works!!!